# Placing multiple Shortcuts in a Wix Installer

Tags: wix, windows-10

I'm trying to add multiple shortcuts under a certain folder using Wix. The code looks like this:

```
<DirectoryRef Id ="TARGETDIR">
    <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="DesktopFolder">
      <Component Id="DesktopP" Guid="61AE5ABE-9ED2-43B0-98C4-3050A40BF061">
        <Shortcut Id="DesktopMyProgramShortcut" Name="$(var.MyProgramLabelShortcut)" Target="[#MyProgramcsproja015777b77a239eeb0bd49c2dafdbe31]" WorkingDirectory="bin"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\Example\Shortcuts" Name="167CE804-4A37-45B8-B010-EB6B3E73BE54" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
      <Directory Id ="ProgramMenuFolderMyProgram" Name ="$(var.MyProgramLabelShortcut)">
        <Component Id="ProgramMenuMyProgram" Guid="A7B4A27B-9367-4AFF-B8CC-D6651B18FBFD">
          <Shortcut Id="ProgramMenuMyProgramShortcut" Name="$(var.MyProgramLabelShortcut)" Target="[#MyProgramcsproja015777b77a239eeb0bd49c2dafdbe31]" WorkingDirectory="bin"/>
          <Shortcut Id="ProgramMenuMyProgramManual" Name="$(var.MyProgramLabelShortcut)" Target="[documents]" Icon="shell32.dll" IconIndex="45"/>
          <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuFolderMyProgram" On="uninstall"/>
          <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\Example\Shortcuts" Name="167CE804-4A37-45B8-B010-EB6B3E73BE54" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </DirectoryRef>
```

The weird behavior is that, when I try to place more than one shortcut, only the second one is added. I've tried placing the `Shortcut` in separate `Components` but still acts that way. In Windows7 works perfectly by the way.

Any suggestion about how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your components `DesktopP` and `ProgramMenuMyProgram` both have the same keypath. Keypaths should be unique per component. Apart from that, according to best practices you should only create a single shortcut to the program within `ProgramMenuFolder`. Help files and other stuff should be available from within the program only. Nobody looks for help files in the start menu anyway.

Comment: Thanks! It was a requirement though it doesn't make any sense as you said...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem had to do with the name of the shortcuts. I guess that, since their names were equal, the first shortcut was overwritten by the second one. I've fixed it changing the name of the second shortcut.

Comment: Wow, I didn't catch that one. Still, changing the keypath of the 2nd component is mandatory. Simply change the *Name* attribute of the `RegistryValue`. (personally I would use the component ID value here to make this a simple copy-paste). Otherwise Windows installer could assume that the 2nd component is already installed when it detects the existence of the keypath registry value created by the 1st component.